# Flag pop-up hidden beneath answer box (and it's still transparent!)

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, flags, comment-flags

The flag window on (a comment to) the last question is hidden beneath the answer box, as shown in the following screenshot:

[image: flag window hidden beneath answer box]

Linked: [Flag window is semi-transparent for downvoted answers](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/288840/2088135), which is currently [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) - this is **not fixed** for flags on comments!

Comment: Jin didn't get enough bacon.

Comment: He must be getting pretty hungry by now...

Comment: haha, comments are just too minor, he's probably too busy.

Comment: Can we use the other one as the dupe target it has an answer.